# How to create dynamic numpy array with 12 rows and unknown columns

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a large number of 12X12 arrays to an empty array.

For Example:

```
import numpy as np
n= int(input("Enter Number"))
abc= np.array([])

for i in range(1,n+1):
     if i%3==0 and i%7==0:
        k1= np.random.rand(12,12)
        abc = np.hstack((abc,k1))
```

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

Python version 3.7
How do I create a dynamic 2D array?

Comment: "I am trying to add a large number of 12X12 arrays to an empty array." *don't do that*.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to StackOverflow and programming. What shouldn't I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I think this is what you need:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(input("Enter Number"))
abc = np.array([[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]])

for i in range(1,n+1):
    if i%3==0:
        k1 = np.random.rand(12,12)
        abc = np.hstack((abc,k1))
```

It looks like you declared `abc` as a 1D array and then `k1` as a 2D array but the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) for hstack say they must be the same shape.

Comment: yes, but how to declare 'abc' as 2D dynamic array so that they can be of the same shape?

Comment: Did you try ```abc = np.array([[]])```?

Comment: Yes, tried that but getting this error:   **ValueError**: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 12

Comment: I had sometime to play around with it and I edited the answer to show you code that works. I hope it's what you wanted.

Comment: **Thanks a lot** now it's working perfectly fine. So in short every empty row must be defined separately.

Comment: Yeah, the dimensions have to match. Maybe there's a better/shorter way to do it, though.